# Downloading 16.04.1 was disrupted. Upon rebooting black screen

Tags: boot, 16.04

Whilst attempting to download 16.04.1 it froze 3 hours in and was disrupted as I tried a PC restart.  Upon rebooting I'm faced with the black screen in the picture:
[image]
I've no idea what my login is (if I ever had one) or how I can progress back to the desktop.  Control Alt F1 or F3 gets nowhere.  Any idea's

Comment: FYI the key combo to get where you are currently is CTRL+ALT+F1. To switch back to the desktop, it is CTRL+ALT+F7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui)

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as your desktop credentials. Log in and reinitiate your window manager.

To restart the WM on Vanilla Ubuntu 16.04, once you've logged in of course:

1. `sudo service sddm restart`
2. `nohup unity --restart`

If your machine is stuck on 14.04:

`sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: just a note, the user asking the question appears to be rather new, judging by their rep, so you should likely include the commands to restart it. `sudo service sddm restart` `nohup unity --restart`

Comment: Yeap, you're right - my fault. I can't comment yet to ask him what Window Manager he was using but some general direction would certainly be of help.

Comment: What about `sudo service lightdm restart`?

Comment: Zalgo's solution works on Ubuntu 16 while I believe LightDM is for 14.04, so both should be included. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: None of the above commands make any difference. Its been suggested that I've broken the configuration as the computer was restarted mid update.

Comment: At this point I'd suggest moving sensitive files to a flash drive and reinstalling. Ubuntu (and every other OS) makes the recommendation to backup before upgrades. There's have been more than a few botched upgrades lately. That said, build a bootable USB and reinstall. If you need some direction for that checkout Linux Live USB Creator. It's always worked for me.