# Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI

Tags: command-line, gui, tty

How to switch between virtual console and GUI in Ubuntu? I wanted to see what key functions would allow me to switch between the two.

Answer (score 17):

In Ubuntu 17.10 and later the virtual consoles are accessed by the keyboard combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. To access the GUI from any virtual console press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

---

In Ubuntu 17.04 and earlier Ubuntu has 6 virtual consoles tty1-tty6 by default which are accessed by the keyboard combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. The virtual console can also be accessed from a black screen if the boot process stops at a black screen when booting. To access the GUI from any virtual console press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

To login from a virtual console:

1. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After you have logged in, you can run commands from the virtual console.
3. To bring up the normal Ubuntu login screen in Ubuntu 16.04 and later run this command:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start graphical.target
   ```

   To bring up the normal Ubuntu login screen in Ubuntu 15.10 and earlier run this command:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start lightdm.service
   ```

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 and later, tty1 (accessed by Ctrl+Alt+F1) contains the login screen, and tty2 (accessed by Ctrl+Alt+F2) contains your actual loaded graphical session.

Comment: It is even possible to login twice on tty1. Then the first GUI is on tty2 and the second on tty3 (or whatever is the next available one).

Comment: its is not working for me. If press Ctrl+Alt+F1 , getting (getting all possibilities )

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F3 also not working.

Answer (score 4):

New answer, for the sake of readability, and for additional info:

### Key combination

You always need to use these keys pressed together.

On normal installations:

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *one of the function keys*.

When used within a VirtualBox virtual machine:

(Unless you configured VirtualBox otherwise,) it's <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + *one of the function keys*.

### Which function key leads where

---

**On GDM3:**

Recent stock Ubuntu releases (with Gnome 3 desktop) (e.g. 17.10 — 20.04 (and probably later)) come with the **GDM3** display manager. If you have not altered the display manager yourself, then you have GDM3.

<kbd>F1</kbd>: The GDM (purple) login screen.

<kbd>F2</kbd>: The graphical session (where you usually want to be)

<kbd>F3</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd>: virtual consoles / TTYs

<kbd>F7</kbd>: Unstable, largely unusable, unaccounted for; avoid it

---

**On LightDM:**

Non-Gnome Ubuntu releases often ship with the **LightDM** display manager. (Or maybe you have switched to LightDM by choice.)

<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd>: Virtual consoles / TTYs

<kbd>F7</kbd>: The graphical session (where you usually want to be)

(This is the behavior how all major display managers behaved before 2017, therefore you will see a lot of guidance that refers to this key assignment. Also, GDM3's new key assignment (discussed above) still catches a lot of non-Gnome users unaware, and they will still suggest using the traditional (now LightDM-only) pattern.)