# Lubuntu gets stuck while booting, possibly due to installing Docker

Tags: boot

I had Lubuntu 16.04 running on my Macbook Pro 9.2, working fine for about 6 months now. Yesterday at work, while booting (without an Ethernet cable in), the boot process froze at the stage shown in the image below.

Then, back at home, I plugged in the Ethernet cable and everything worked fine for the evening.

Then, this morning, still at home and with the Ethernet cable plugged in, the boot process got stuck at the same stage (image below).

The newest thing I installed was docker (and docker.io), but that was about 3 days ago, and booting worked fine for the next two days. Still, a Docker message shows up around halfway in the attached image, could that have something to do with it?

I don't even know how/where to start attacking this problem. I'd be grateful for any hints on where to start searching.

/Edit: In the [possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), the closest thing I could find in the section **If an update or something else caused your boot problem** was "How do I investigate boot and partition issues?". This deals with GRUB issues mostly. I'll try running Rescatux too, but I'd hope that someone might recognize a problem in my screenshot's output.

[image: Stuck boot screen]

Comment: Thanks, this link has a few general guidelines, but the closest one to my problem was about grub boot issues (the link titled "How do I investigate boot and partition issues?"), and as I see it, at the stage where my problem arises, grub is already done. I've already prepared a Live ISO, and will just backup my home directory and reinstall if I can't find an easy fix.

Comment: You can uninstall packages from the virtual console even if Ubuntu can't boot to the GUI desktop: https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui/917386#917386

Comment: True, but I'd have to be able to boot for that :)

Comment: No, you don't have to boot for that. You only need the kernel for that and your screenshot clearly shows that the kernel has started and is able to initialize subsystems and print boot diagnostic messages.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know! Thanks, I'll try that when I'm home.