# Ctrl+Alt+F1 is not working anymore after installing VMware View Agent

Tags: command-line, vmware, tty

I have successfully installed GUI/Python/VMware View Agent on one Ubuntu VM.
But the second day after I powered it on, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> was not working any more.
[And I can't use terminal from GUI as well.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100007/terminal-cant-be-launched-in-gui)
Is there any possibility to back to Command line?

**Update:**
Finally I figured out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is not functional because I installed VMware View Agent.
But so far I don't have any solution.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F6 try this

Comment: Does [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/q/917320/507051) help? To quote the answer there: “Starting with Ubuntu 17.10 the virtual consoles are accessed by the keyboard combinations **Ctrl+Alt+F3 to Ctrl+Alt+F6**. To access the GUI from any virtual console press the keyboard combination Ctrl+Alt+F2.”

Comment: I tried all the Fn key but none is working, there is no any response for any of them

Comment: IT solution is reinstall the system, I mean it's a kind of solution but not a good one. Maybe any of you can help.

Comment: What about in recovery mode? Can you boot there are get a root shell to uninstall the program?

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.