# Terminal can't be launched in GUI

Tags: command-line

When I click on terminal it shows in the menu but after few seconds, it disappears.
I have no idea how to make it work.
By the way, since the GUI installed this terminal never working.
Is it related to rights?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by rights? Are you using Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @Kulfy I guess the word _rights_ means _permissions_ (they are the same in my native language, too).

Comment: @Melebius since OP said terminal isn't working since installation and far as I know even guests can launch terminal. I was just asking OP what kind of rights he is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Can you launch xterm? I've seen this issue before and what I had to do is to reinstall the terminal. If you can launch xterm you can do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Does TTY work? Can you access terminal through pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>?