# Log into tty and do not launch gnome-shell

Tags: login, login-screen, tty

When working on my laptop I would like to be able to log in directly into a tty without launching the X server. This saves battery and is also pleasant on the eyes since the screen background is truly black. Then if I need to do some web browsing I would like to launch the desktop environment with `startx` or similar.  How can I accomplish this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable GUI in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242965/how-to-disable-gui-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-tty-and-gui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure Ubuntu desktop to boot into the text mode, like the server:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Then, if you are working in text mode and want to launch the graphical environment:

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```