# How to disable lightdm and use the terminal to log in

Tags: 18.04

Some time ago I tried to upgrade my ubuntu version from 16.04 lts to 18.04 lts, the PC powered off during the upgrade.

So ubuntu broke making it enter in a log in loop. I follow all the internet tutorials to solve it, even changed from GMD to lightdm, nothing happened, I give up.

Now i start a graphic section opening a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>), logging in and using startx.

**So I want to disable lightdm** because: 1 it doesn't work. 2 to have more resources.

**But here is the thing** due to the unfinished upgrade of ubuntu I have kinda a "non-ubuntu" version of gnome, when I reboot my pc after the uncompleted upgrade of ubuntu I was surprised due my new desktop had no taskbar, just a little tab that says activities and at the right of it the activity that's running right now.

To be fair it is kinda clean, I accustomed to change between programs running with the keyboard
but any ways, any help is appreciated

PD: after I rebooted my pc after the ubuntu upgrade it says that is is ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Advice: Fix your broken release-upgrade first before tinkering with your display manager.

Comment: If you only want to use a command line shell, you might as well remove `xserver-xorg-core`. But beware, there is no easy way to undo this.

Comment: replay for 1: No, i don't want to only use the command line, i just want to disable the graphic section manager.

replay for 2: i don't want to update my distro, because:
1: my pc doesn't meet the requirements of ubuntu 20.04
2: my pc has a emmc of 32 gb only(i know it's a crap but something is better than nothing)

Comment: For both 16.04 and 18.04 you should be able to change the default systemd target - see for example [How to disable GUI in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243040/178692)

Comment: I would **not** try and login to GUI, or make changes until you know the *release-upgrade* has completed... limiting yourself to terminal to ensure it's done..   Once *release-upgrade* has completed, you can reboot and will likely find you can log in normally; however with every change you make before then, the chances to re-install being required increase.