# Switch from text mode to graphical mode

Tags: boot, gui, text-mode

Suppose one boots their Ubuntu installation with `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` or `text` as a kernel boot option/parameter. They will eventually arrive at a terminal-based interface to login and perform tasks and so on. If one wishes to switch into graphical mode, into the graphical login screen, without rebooting into such, how does one do it?

(I am using Ubuntu 22.04, BTW.)

Comment: You should be able to *isolate* the `graphical.target` - basically the opposite of this [How to disable GUI in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243040/178692)