# Is there any conflict between nohup and mpirun?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, logout, signal, mpi

I want to start a big simulation on an ubuntu desktop computer. I have physical (not remote) access to this PC. This simulation may take some weeks. The command to start the process is:

```bsh
mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel | tee log
```

Where `icoFoam` is the executable and `-parallel` is needed as its option.
This command prints data in terminal. Some times the terminal is closed or the OS is logged-out randomly during long simulations and due to this, the process terminates. I tried to figure it out by a couple of alternative commands:

```bsh
nohup mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel > log  & 
nohup mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel > log  & disown & 
nohup mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel | tee log & disown & 
nohup mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel | tee log & disown & > /dev/null 2>& 1 & nohup mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel > /dev/null 2>& 1  &
systemd-run --scope --user mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel | tee log &
systemd-run --scope --user mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel | tee log & disown &
systemd-run --scope --user nohup mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel | tee log & disown &
tmux
```

**Results**
Except form `tmux`, using any one of these commands, the process is terminated when I close the terminal.
`tmux` is also terminated when I log out from my user account.

**My Findings**

1. As the simplest workaround, I mixed **nohup** and **disown** ( [from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420594/why-process-killed-with-nohup) ).
2. I guessed that commands including `tee`, are terminated because of `SIGPIPE` caused by closing the terminal ([from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134924/i-am-using-why-isnt-the-process-running-in-the-background)). Therefore I used redirection to a log file or `/dev/null` ([from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134924/i-am-using-why-isnt-the-process-running-in-the-background)), both of which were also terminated by closing the terminal.
3. I also examined `systemd-run`. But it also is terminated by closing the terminal.
4. To see whether the program has installed its own handler, I executed this:

   ```bsh
   nohup mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel > log  &
   grep Sig /proc/$!/status
   ```

   Which returns

   ```bsh
   SigIgn: 0000000000000000
   ```

   Therefore, I guess this is the case, i.e. `mpirun` has installed its own handler overriding the protection of `nohup` ([from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420594/why-process-killed-with-nohup)).
5. I don't know if it is possible to send a custom handler to `mpirun` in order not to override `nohup`.

**My Question**
I want to execute the following command such that it prints output in the terminal as long as the terminal is not closed, and also the process is not terminated by closing the terminal or logging out from the user account.

```bsh
mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Executable: OpenFOAM
mpirun (Open MPI): 2.1.1

**Update**
By log out, I mean pressing log out button (image), not lock-screen (super+L)
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "The OS is logged out randomly" - it's not clear if you are referring to  a normal lock-screen or if you are referring to a desktop *crash*. A crash will terminate all child processes and lose all your work...which might be what you are describing. 'nohup' won't help you survive a crash - crashes must be diagnosed and fixed.

Comment: @user535733 OK. How about "logging out deliberately"? I don't mean lock-screen, I mean pressing log out button as included in the update in the question. Does a deliberately logging out terminates all child processes? And the main question still is, why nohup terminates when I close the terminal? Thank you for your informative comment.

Comment: Dear @user535733 , When I leave my pc, how can I somehow lock tty in order to keep it safe from the others to cause interruption, as well as keep the processes to continue, without being killed by this?

Comment: Use a *terminal multiplexer* like `screen` or `tmux`. Those run in the background *even when you're not logged in* to any tty or desktop, and they provide a stable parent process for your ongoing jobs to be children of. Both applications are easy to use (try a few tutorials first), and both are in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting the job *from within a desktop environment*, so the jobs are children of that desktop. When the desktop ends, for whatever reason, all children automatically end, too. 'nohup' won't save them - logout removes the display that output should print to, which should also cause a fatal error.

Consider running tmux in a *[tty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui)* instead of a *terminal window*. Then the process can run forever regardless of whatever the desktop is doing.

Comment: That's it. The problem was exactly "starting the job from within a desktop environment".

Comment: @Alish, now you can vote up, have nice time. This is an interesting answer. I never thought about it this way, input/output stream connections. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same configuration (Ubuntu 18.04, OpenFoam v7, Open MPI 2.1.1) here and I am facing the same issues. The only solution that helped were the steps described in [this post](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/441317-Nohup-problem-with-MPI-and-remote-ssh?p=2183812#post2183812):

1. Start the window manager from your console using `screen` and press Enter.
2. In the screen console, you can then input your commands according to your needs, p. e.

   ```
   nohup mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel > log  &
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to "detach" the terminal to the created "screen".
4. Now you should be able to close the terminal window without killing the `mpi` processes.
5. In order to go back to the screen, open a new terminal and type `screen -DR`. It should open the last screen.
6. In the screen, type `exit`, if you want to exit the screen.

Notation: If you created more than one screen, `screen -DR` shows a list with all screen sessions. Type `screen -r [session number]` to go to the screen or `screen -X -S 63896 quit` to quit the screen.
It is a bit clumsy workaround, but I hope that helps, looking forward that this bug (or feature?) is resolved in future versions.

For further information refer to `man screen`.

Comment: Thanks; `tmux` is also a multiplexer like `screen`; but based on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/236158/tmux-vs-screen), I prefered `tmux`. And neither `nohup` nor `mpirun` are buggy; the situation is due to over-riding the handler.

Answer (score 1):

A second way is to use `setsid` to run `mpirun` in a new session. The advantage is that this session is not killed when the terminal is closed (hang-up signal, `SIGHUP`), as suggested in general [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53286/407516) and more specifically [here](https://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/p2Ch2Dlm/ompi-users-openmpi-exits-when-subsequent-tail-f-in-script-is-interrupted#post12). The syntax is simple:

`setsid mpirun -np 100 icoFoam -parallel > log  &`

In order to terminate `mpirun` manually for any reason, kill one of the `icofoam` processes with `htop`, press <kbd>F9</kbd> and send a `SIGKILL` by pressing <kbd>9</kbd>. All other `icofoam` processes and the `mpirun` process should then be killed too. As an alternative, type `killall mpirun` as proposed [here](https://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/p2Ch2Dlm/ompi-users-openmpi-exits-when-subsequent-tail-f-in-script-is-interrupted#post15).