# after reboot when I chose ubuntu to open, there is just a terminal kind of and not able to see any gui

Tags: gui, reboot

I shut down my pc directly and tried to restart it. But after reboot when I chose ubuntu to open, there is just a terminal kind of and not able to see any gui. Can anyone please help me get gui back??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) or [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui)

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.