# How to get login window to come up? 20.04.2

Tags: startup

Just today when I turned on my 18.04 computer it starts up and has the "Ubuntu" screen .. . then it turns purple . . . and that is all.   There is no login.  I was just hitting random keys, then I think I hit enter and entered my password and it came up.  I got it to update software and when it was done it asks if you want to upgrade to 20.04 so I thought maybe that would fix this login problem.   Well, after an hour or so it had upgraded and then restarted but again the login window didn't come up.   I did get in again but would like to know how to get it to startup properly and get to the login screen without all of the waiting and key hitting I keep trying.
Clearly something is broken.
Thanks.

Comment: That purple login screen is called the GDM login. I don't know a solution, but I would suggest a temporary workaround: try to switch to a virtual console, then back to the GDM login screen, and see if it brings the form up. Here is how you can switch back and forth: https://askubuntu.com/a/1329549/1157519

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 computers hooked up to the same monitor.  This one was with the VGA.   I took that one off and put on the HDMI and it worked.   It had been having trouble with the display so I thought I'd try that.  It worked.  But thanks for the link to switch consoles. . . things like that are helpful to have.