# Cannot get back GUI Ubuntu 20.04 VirtualBox

Tags: command-line, 20.04, virtualbox, gui, tty

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on VirtualBox and everything was working fine until I restarted my PC. Unfortunately now I cant seem to get back my GUI. I see alot of commands about holding Right Click + FN key. But all that does is open a new `tty` command prompt. I also see using Alt+ Arrow Keys but that simply pages the tty screens.
Appreciate it if someone could assist me in getting back my GUI. The commands may have changed cause simply using CTRL+Alt +f7 as said in this link , does not work
[Switching between virtual console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-and-gui)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get back to GUI with `chvt` comand.

```shell
$ man chvt
```

> chvt - change foreground virtual terminal
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> chvt [option...]  N
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The command chvt N makes /dev/ttyN the foreground terminal.  (The
> corresponding screen is created if it did not exist yet.  To get
> rid of unused VTs, use deallocvt(1).)  The key combination
> (Ctrl-)LeftAlt-FN (with N in the range 1-12) usually has a
> similar effect.

Log in on any tty command prompt and then try this.

```shell
$ sudo chvt 7
```

It would give you this error if you run it without ***sudo*** privileges

> Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.