# How to close virtual terminal?

Tags: virtual-console

I opened terminal pressed
Ctrl-Alt-F2
I saw virtual terminal. I couldn't return to Graphical desktop.
I pressed power button.
I again pressed power button.
It displays
***/dev/nvme0n1p1:clean, 294223/1220608files, 4638309/4882432 blocks***
How do I get back?

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-F1` or `Ctrl-Alt-F4`, depending.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-and-gui) and ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/q/882385/)