# Never seen this screen before not sure what to do

Tags: boot, 20.04, virtual-console

I recently upgraded to Windows 11. I am not sure if this is what caused the problem or if it is some other underlying issue, but I tried to boot Ubuntu today using Oracle VirtualBox and I was greeted by this screen that I keep getting every time I boot up.

[image: Screen that I keep getting every time I boot up]

I ran `apt list --upgradable`, but this makes no difference. I have done that and rebooted and it didn't work either. I just can't get into the desktop environment.

Comment: What does command `systemctl status default.target` report?

Comment: So... that is the OS. What exact version (and flavor) of Ubuntu is installed? Did you install Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? Also, what happens when you do `startx` in that terminal?

Comment: [Switching between virtual console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/q/917320/) will get you back into the desktop environment.

Comment: looks like a headless server installation to me

Comment: @steeldriver when I run that command it says this https://i.gyazo.com/7a83a8065325e682711513caca6dc5a5.png

Comment: @cocomac I installed the desktop version I am fairly sure and its Ubuntu 20.04 as for flavours I just downloaded the system image off the official ubuntu page I didn't download Xubuntu or anything like that and when I run the startx command it just says that the command can't be found

Comment: @ShinglesGordon98 What is the full filename of the ISO you downloaded? Was it something like Ubuntu Server?

Comment: this is the file name ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64