# ubuntu 21.10 boot problem[tty1]

Tags: 21.10, tty

I am facing such a problem while booting my computer:

[image: TTY Login]

I’m using Ubuntu 21.10. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Hello. what error? That small bit of text should be typed in not shown as a picture.

Comment: I don't know what the error was. I just turned on the computer and this screen came up. I searched but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Not an error. Try logging in and fully update the system (sudo apt update && sudo apt full-ugrade` then `sudo reboot now`.

Comment: It looks like you configured your system as a server, not a desktop.

Comment: I was using the desktop version. I had shut down the computer properly. When I opened it 2 hours later, a screen like this appeared.

Comment: Try @ChanganAuto's solution. If that doesn't work, again log in and try `startx`. This will give you an error. Paste the error into your question so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: I solved the problem. It's a simple problem, but I still don't understand why I'm getting such an error. I had to reinstall ubuntu-desktop with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. the problem has disappeared. Thank you all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-and-gui)

Answer (score 0):

Login with your username then enter password
Then run fsck /dev/sdax ;sdax may be sda2 or sda3 which is in your screen