# Ubuntu 20.04 not starting after first encryption password

Tags: login, password, login-screen

I start my computer, a Lenovo Thinkpad. Ubuntu 20.04 is asking for login encrypt disk password. Normally for the past year it was starting and asking for a second login password, but now only a black screen appears with a blinking underscore character in the top left corner. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del, restarting, then asking for an encryption password and then getting stuck again after this.

Comment: what is "ubuntu 20"? do you mean Ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10 or something else? Ubuntu Core 20 is a completely different thing from either of these, and probably not what you have.

Comment: what does it show after asking for the encryption password? Do you know the password and did you enter it correctly?

Comment: @karel Thank you for your help editing my question :)

Comment: What happens if you try to login from a virtual console: https://askubuntu.com/a/917386/ ? Even if you can't login you can still run commands from a console.

Comment: @Esther Thank you for your support. As I remember it is Ubuntu 20.03 (?). It was the free download iso around beginning of 2021. Since April 2021 the boot sector was full, and no updates possible anymore. When I press „Enter“-key while starting after disc encrypt code, a white window is opening. Showing options with „F“-keys for some seconds. Than going on like before, and stuck again with this like before.

Comment: @karel Thank you for the support. When I press  combinations Ctrl+Alt+F1 to Ctrl+Alt+F6 it asking for login. What login is wanted? All I write answer is „Login incorrect“. I got the computer „ready-to-use“. It was set up from a friend. I don‘t know the login name. I got the two passwords for the two self-opening windows....

Comment: Is it here allowed for me to share my Telegram name here and talk in the messenger? Maybe it’s easier? Of course, when the problem is solved, I would post the solution here for the community.

Comment: why don't you ask the friend who set it up for the login? They would know. Although it should be the same as the username you usually use, do you know what your username on the computer is?

Comment: @Esther He is not answering anymore. Since a year, I donˋt know why. I don‘t used a username, just got the window with a red frame asking for the password. Than it was loading, and I got a purple screen with asking for the second password.

Comment: @plumtree You can also use this chatroom for discussing your question: [Discussion on question by plumtree: Ubuntu 20.04 not starting after first encryption password](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136468/discussion-on-question-by-plumtree-ubuntu-20-04-not-starting-after-first-encrypt)

Comment: @karel Thank you for the chatroom. It says I have to have 20 points. Where to get them?

Comment: I tried to add you as a chatroom user, but I don't have permission to add you as a user because your reputation < 20, so let's use this question's chat for now. When there are too many comments, Ask Ubuntu will automatically create a new chatroom for this question where you have permission to chat.

Comment: @karel Thank you very much! I apologize for the delays, I had difficulties to write more often.

Comment: What can I do, what do you need to know?

Comment: In an old photo I found a name and login. Now I got a „Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-41-generic x86_64).   The command line shows the name and than :~$ and than the blinking line.   How do I come now back to my purple-orange color desktop, with the cat picture on the surface?

Comment: @karel In an old photo I found a name and login. Now I got a „Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-41-generic x86_64).   The command line shows the name and than :~$ and than the blinking line.   How do I come now back to my purple-orange color desktop, with the cat picture on the surface?

Comment: @Esther In an old photo I found a name and login. Now I got a „Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-41-generic x86_64).   The command line shows the name and than :~$ and than the blinking line.   How do I come now back to my purple-orange color desktop, with the cat picture on the surface?

Comment: Maybe you want to share your Telegram name in the Chatroom, so I can contact you in a secret chat and send photos.

Comment: @karel I found the login. Next problem appeared. Please could you have a look on the next question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412337/how-do-i-come-back-to-my-purple-orange-color-desktop-with-the-cat-picture-on-th

Comment: @Esther I found the login. Next problem appeared. Please could you have a look on the next question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412337/how-do-i-come-back-to-my-purple-orange-color-desktop-with-the-cat-picture-on-th