# How do I come back to my purple-orange color desktop, with the cat picture on the surface?

Tags: boot, login

After password for disc encryption, I get a black window. With CTRL+ALT+F2 I were asked to login and password. Than I got a „Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-41-generic x86_64). The command line shows the name and than :~$ and than the blinking line. How do I come now back to my purple-orange color desktop, with the cat picture on the surface?

Comment: Alrighty. So you are in what is called a TTY. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/66198/1438484) for what it is. It is basically a command-line only version of Ubuntu. If simply rebooting doesn't help, type in `startx`, and press enter. What happens then? Side note: once you fix this, consider upgrading to 20.04.4 as it is newer.

Comment: @cocomac Thank you very much!  I got a package of information; systems versions, Kernel, xorg, markers, logfile. At the end „fatal server error: (EE) cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices. [...] consult X.Org Foundation support at http://Wiki.x.org for help. Please also check log file at „/var/log/Xorg.0.log“ for additional information.  Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.  xinit: giving up. xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused. xinit: server error

Comment: @cocomac  Sorry, I forgot: the first answer line says „xauth:  file /home/[my loginname]/.Xauthority does not exist“

Comment: Remark: it shows here Ubuntu 20.04.1. And the boot sector and others were already full long time ago. Nothing was updated for more than a year.