# Ubuntu boots to tty login

Tags: boot, grub2, wine, shutdown

The last thing I was doing on my computer was installing the wine application through the terminal. The request for the download was taking forever so I just shutdown my computer forcefully without stopping the process of the download. Went to work, came back the next day, instead of loading into the regular Ubuntu login screen, it loads into some sort of terminal login screen.

How do I fix it?

I tried

```
vim /etc/default/grub
```

To edit the GRUB settings to try and load into the GRUB menu.

```
sudo update-grub
```

```
sudo reboot
```

But it doesn't reboot into GRUB, it just comes back to the tty login terminal.

[image: verbose boot]

[image: tty login]

Comment: I don't understand your question; any details in the title should also exist in your question as some browsers don't show the title when reading the question text.  By shutdown do you mean you entered a shutdown via GUI?, via terminal? or via SysRq? or what?  ie. was it a *safe* or *clean* shutdown? or are you trying to fix issues due to bad/unclean shutdown?

Comment: So before I force shutdown the computer(holding the power button until the screen computer shuts down), I was trying to install wine from terminal but the request to the page was on a constant loop of trying to request the download, so I forcefully shutdown without stopping the process thinking nothing was gonna happen, went to work, came back and opened my computer up to use it, loads into the terminal login, but I don't know what the issue is, tried "reboot" and it reboots into the same terminal screen, I'm just trying to get my computer back, but I don't know what happened or how to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I'll suggest you don't use the power button unless you really have to (eg. *a kernel panic has occurred and you have no other options*) as aborting your package upgrade/install would have been safer, or just giving a command to `shutdown now`, or if *lazy* or in a real hurry skipping all that and directing the kernel to shutdown safely now (ie. SysRq commands direct to linux)...   FYI:  I feel the *update or something else caused your boot problem* in that duplicate applies to you.

Comment: Myself after power failure (*which you caused using power button*) I'd boot *live* media and perform `fsck` (*fs* checks) then try boot normally (*which I'd expect to fix issue normally*)..  Your complication is you weren't specific as to what was occurring during your attempted package install, thus you may have more complex problems due to corrupted [*package*] databases depending on where it was when you forced the power-off... ie. don't use power button when better options exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-and-gui)

Comment: I performed ```fsck``` and it failed, it rebooted into the tty login terminal screen.