# Ubuntu 23.04 now boots to a TTY

Tags: boot, tty

My laptop at home runs Ubuntu 23.04, and has worked well for some time.  Last night I was prompted to do an update, which I did as usual using apt from a terminal, and all appeared to complete correctly.

On reboot however, the system now boots to a TTY, rather than starting the DE.

I looked at this, which seemed similar, but found nothing particularly helpful there:
[Ubuntu boots to tty login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433983/ubuntu-boots-to-tty-login)

Would someone mind pointing me to a how-to on how to get my DE back please?!

[Edited] I should point out that on boot, it gives me the prompt to unlock the hard-drive encryption, then just boots to a login prompt in tty1.

Many thanks,
K

Comment: Did you uninstall your Desktop-Environment?

Comment: I certainly didn't see that happening while the update was going on.
I guess when I get home I can just try typing 'startx' and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, sorted now. But this is in no way 'an answer' I'm afraid.

Basically I tried the 'startx' thing, and it claimed to have no knowledge of my /home partition. I just gave up and did a clean reinstall, restore from backups, tweak a few bits and pieces, and all fine again.