# Ubuntu 20.04.2 stuck at tty screen

Tags: upgrade, tty

Recently I tried to update my Ubuntu to 20.04.2 (after getting too many notification about it).
As newbie I follow some instructions, then found myself on this dark screen. Help me to return to my desktop screen please.

[image]

I tried running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, and got this result:

```
Reading package lists.. Done. 
Building dependency tree Reading state information.. Done. 
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Try reinstalling the desktop - run this command: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. If you get any error messages, please include them in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about the version number you tried to update to? What was the version  number you were upgrading from?

Comment: @David thanks for response! İt was 20.04. Actually I am not sure about version I tried to updated to. I guess it is the version reflect on screen file I shared above.

Comment: 20.04.2 is quite a bit out of date. A fully updated 20.04 would be 20.04.6. So I am confused as to what it is you tried to do.

Comment: @David wow I did not even know 20.04.6 exists. If I can return to my old desktop, it would be enough to be happy right now)

Comment: It seems there are more errors if you get the message `E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop`. Maybe your network is not working either?

Comment: @ArturMeinild But same network is working on other devices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-and-gui)