# Start GNOME from terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm new and not familiar with Linux and would like to know how I can start the user graphical interface GNOME. In the terminal I entered startx but after the process has been done nothing happens.
I work with 20.04.
It would be great if I could find the solution here or anyone can help me.
Many thanks and best regards

Comment: `grep -ri exec /usr/share/xsessions/`

Comment: So did you start with a 20.04 *server* installation, and add a Gnome package(s) to it? If so, which package(s)? Or  did you start with a different desktop distribution and removed package(s)? Please help us to help you by being as specific as possible about your situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-and-gui)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-session --session=gnome
```