# Logging in blank screen on upgrade to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: upgrade

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 from 22.10, upgrade indicated no errors. I rebooted onto Ubuntu 23.03, the reboot produced a blank screen. I powered off and waited. Powered back on, the Ubuntu logo appeared when through all the usual processes but still no login screen just blank. Any assistance would be appreciated. Do I need to do a complete install? The host machine is a Dell XPS15.

Comment: did you first use `try Ubuntu` from the iso before committing to the upgrade to see how it performed?

Comment: No, this was an upgrade from 22.10

Comment: I have the same issue with a ZaReason 'strata' notebook. It is based on old NVidia GF-108 and lspci says  "VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M]" - I don't get a blank screen, I get a blank screen with what looks like a text cursor in the top left corner; it doesn't blink, and ctrl-alt-Fn does not let me select text-mode consoles.

Comment: I do notice this in Xorg.0.log:
[    98.248] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    98.248] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1366 x 768

I had this problem on Raspberry Ubuntu where this resolution was invalid for my monitor, and my notebook also does not have this mode, so could the answer be found in "How do I set my default resolution in UbuntuStudio 23.04?"

Comment: Tried many variations of grub.cfg and xorg.conf modeline settings, also generated an xorg.conf using nvidia-xsettings, and while grub.cfg may change the textmode messages during boot, after the UbuntuStudio logo stops spinning, it goes black, and then I get a text screen with a non-blinking cursor, no login screen, no console switching with Ctrl-Alt-Fn, and my only option is to ssh in and order a reboot. I'm shut down.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-and-gui)

Comment: I totally get it that you tried to upgrade but my question was did you try `Try Ubuntu` from the iso to see how it performed.

Comment: No, I didn't "Try Ubuntu" from the iso beforehand. This was an upgrade I wasn't expecting any issues. As I said, no issues on the install of 23.04, and the reboot had no issues, it just produced a blank screen.

Comment: karel- this didn't answer my question

Comment: MrG - I also had a blinking cursor but after the power off and on that disappeared, now just a blank screen. I have a feeling it might be an issue with my Nvidia driver. A complete install might be the only resolution.

Comment: I can confirm that it is the nvidia driver in my situation, although it *should* be possible to set the corrected default (somewhere?) any modes or modelines I added were rejected as invalid.

I did discover multi-user mode and switched to that so I could login (and get at my files) but that also meant I could run startx from within my user account, and this confirmed the block: the nvidia driver cannot connect to xorg and bails. Historically this is blamed on the driver not matching the kernel. Using nouveaux after purging nvidia is ugly low-res, but at least I can kinda work.

Comment: I have the same problem I use many way, install nvidia graphic , change iframe of boot, update fron 22.01 or install from iso

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem after a 23.04 upgrade. The only way to get the display to work was to boot with the nomodeset option, but then my external monitor wasn't detected. I've solved enabling Wayland, that for some reason was disabled.

You can check if Wayland is disabled in favor of Xorg with

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If the output is x11, you can enable Wayland editing the file /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and comment the line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

or modify it to

```
WaylandEnable=true
```

then reboot pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del and be sure to select Ubuntu clicking on the gear icon at the login screen.