# Stuck in terminal login page

Tags: login

I am trying to login to my Ubuntu system and every time I do this happens. I tried entering my login name and it doesn't work. I tried to enter commands but I couldn't. And I tried rebooting but it didn't work. How can I fix this? The image link is below

[image]

Comment: pres ctrl+alt+f2

Comment: Please try to be more descriptive than *"it doesn't work"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-and-gui)