# How to log out of Ubuntu without gui?

Tags: logout

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> didn't work, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> don't open terminal.

I don't know what windows manager I accidentally went into but I know if I can log out and switch it I will be fine. All I get is a black screen with Ubuntu written on the bottom, like the flash screen on Fossa, which is what I'm running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-tty-and-gui)

Comment: ^D is the *end of file* character, thus if entered at the start of a line will cause a terminal, or session (*if that's what is running*) to end as end of command line input was reached (ie. *you told it to logout/end session*)  A WM or *window manager* is a GUI tool, so if you're running a WM you've started a GUI session & your details are *unclear*.

Comment: There are no buttons for me to press because this wm is broken. That's why I said no gui. Karel understood what I meant, thanks Karel. When I accessed the terminal thanks to karel it turned out I wasnt logged in to begin with and the problem is deeper thani thought.

Comment: You can run a GUI without a WM; in the 1980s that was the usual way it was done.. X11 [now Xorg] allowed graphic mapping of screen, and you could move *windows* around via terminal command... a WM is a later tool that allows easier drag/resize (with a mouse) than using your GUI without a WM and thus being restricted to terminal commands.

Comment: I suppose I meant a desktop manager. Anyway I've tried changing wm and dms and reinstalled lightdm and upgraded the os and still I have a black screen with a cursor

Comment: A DM or *display manager* is likewise optional..  `lightdm` is a DM or *greeter* and allows you to enter username/password & start a predefined session, but isn't required for GUI either.  It maybe helpful if you're specific as to what you're using, you mention *focal* which is vague; as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server is *fossa*, as is Ubuntu Core 20; both of which don't use GUI, DM or WM by default. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop does use a GUI, but doesn't use `lightdm` either, as GNOME is the default GUI (thus GDM ir GNOME DM is used). Your details are *unclear*.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I had accidentally logged into openbox without knowing it, which I was calling a wm but I guess it's a DM, and I don't know what that is or how to use it. Finally I found a thread saying try typing startx into the terminal, and it started so I was able to log out properly finally and switch from openbox back to what they call "Ubuntu", which I guess is gnome

Comment: `openbox` is a WM, it's the WM used by Lubuntu actually (Lubuntu uses LXQt which is WM *agnostic*, Lubuntu uses `openbox` as its WM).  A default `openbox` has no config until it's created (*excluding a rather limited skeleton*), it also has no background/wallpaper (*different tools are expected to do that; thus you may see a black screen OR even whatever was last seen on your screen before `openbox` started, thus not even realizing you've left the prior screen/DM*) thus yes it's easy to get confused by a WM alone (*its less featured than a DE or desktop*). GNOME is a DE, which can use openbox