# After updating to 22.04.3 I get a blank login screen asking for my username and password, despite inputting it and rebooting from USB nothing works

Tags: usb, login, password, virtual-console

I'm using a Surface Go tablet. This is what pops up when I log in, I just blurred out my name information.

[image: This is what pops up when I log in, I just blurred out my name information]

I put in my password and user, but it just won't work. I tried booting from a USB again, but that did nothing. Is there any way to fix this or just start over again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-tty-and-gui)

Comment: @karel I'll check and see if it works when I find time, thank you!