# Problems GUI don't start

Tags: command-line, gui

I turn on the PC and start on a gnu grub version 2.06 screen.
Generally typing "exit" starts the normal graphical interface.
But now when I do it, the following screen appears:
`Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ubuntu -22-04 tty1`

`ubuntu-22-04 login:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-tty-and-gui)

Answer (score 0):

login to term session then type

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```