# Cannot switch back to GUI interface

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu through Oracle virtual box and somehow my virtual box has stuck in the CLI and I'm not able to go back to the GUI interface here I'm attaching the screenshot of the same.

[image: Screenshot Of the ubuntu screen]

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F7 or `systemctl restart gdm3`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-tty-and-gui)