Ubuntu 22.04 How to get a tty?
I use Ubuntu 22.04 and fcitx input. Sometimes, when the computer goes to sleep and is in Chinese input mode, I cannot log in again. Sometimes ctrl space will switch to English input and I manage to login, but sometimes nothing works and I have to force shutdown and reboot.
So I thought I would start a tty with ctrl alt f4 or some other f, login, and gracefully reboot
But nothing happens.
Now I am logged in to Ubuntu 22.04, but ctrl alt f4 does nothing.
Trying chvt I get this error:

pedro@pedro-MSI:~$ chvt 5 Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to
the console.
pedro@pedro-MSI:~$

How can I make ctrl alt f* work? Or is that no longer available in Ubu 22.04?

This is available on all Linux platforms. Did you try ctrl+alt+F1 or F2?

Did you try all the combinations of Ctrl+Alt+F5 through Ctrl+Alt+F8 too? See also this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power

... the one that's reserved by default (per /etc/systemd/logind.conf) is tty6

Addressing the underlying keyboard lockup issue might help.

This may be similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1522242/i-crashed-the-system-by-changing-the-desktop-background-to-an-xml-file/1522260#1522260

Just now I tried ctrl alt f1 to f8 but nothing happens. I am logged in normally. In the past, I have used this when things went wrong to log out gracefully.

Here is how you access a tty: https://askubuntu.com/q/917320/1157519

FWIW Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console. is a normal response when you try to run chvt as an unprivileged user

Aha, just tried that as sudo, it worked ok, and also got me back here sudo chvt 1 Thanks for that tip!

But I don't have a terminal when I am trying to login! How can I get a tty then?
